# Defining a TypeScript object type where the type of a property depends on the value of another one of type literal

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

Please check the following example:

```js
type MyLiterals = 'a' | 'b'

type MyObject<T extends MyLiterals> = {
    a: T,
    b: T extends 'a' ? number : string
}

// thit works
let obj2: MyObject<'b'> = {
    a: 'b',
    b: ''
}

// Generic type 'MyObject' requires 1 type argument(s)
let obj1: MyObject = {
    a: 'b',
    b: ''
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do with the second example, where the value of the generic is inferred by the value assigned to the first property?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can create a union of all possible pairs.

Here I leveraged [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) to do it:

```js
type MyObjectFactory<T extends MyLiterals> = T extends any ? {
    a: T,
    b: T extends 'a' ? number : string
} : never

type MyObject = MyObjectFactory<MyLiterals>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAyBLYEBOBDANgZygXigHJ1CoAfIgI0ICgbRJYQB5SgKwgGNgAxdbgPaoQAHgAqUCAA8UAOwAmuOEhQYcAPnxQJ0uYqjpZIKAH4oAbxpRrBgFzaANFZuV7OmRAW5ipM7ICuALaUaFD22MCoiLIA5jQAvmFQshAAbmh0DNBwrBzcWjnsXLz8wEKiyshoWNjqdAD09VDAABbIUADuQgDW2DSYEMBQAuwATPaFeUMEljZ2VIROc65EtPENTQDinmiInM3g0ISTxaSoEACO-ojnuACMB4zoqDFBnsAAFNgAlP2Dw+w7hMWEV8jNnNZ0PZCNQli5oWsgA)

Another way to write it:

```js
type MyObject = MyLiterals extends infer T ? T extends any ? {
    a: T,
    b: T extends 'a' ? number : string
} : never : never
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that ok with a function ?

```
function setIt<T extends MyLiterals>(a:T, b : T extends 'a' ? number : string) : MyObject<T>{
    return {a,b}
}

let obj1;

obj1 = setIt('a',12); // OK
obj1 = setIt('b',12); // Do not compile
```